# Encoding problem printing dictionary in Robotframework

Tags: python, encoding, robotframework

I have a problem to show correctly a specific key in a dictionary in Robotframework.

I have a dictionary with this key (latin-1 chars):

```
${dict}=     create dictionary  Nº Cartão=123
```

When I try to use the variable dict the log shows:

```
{u'N\xba Cart\xe3o': u'123'}
```

If I put the string in a simple variable:

```
${dict2}=     set variable     Nº cartão
```

Log shows:

```
Nº Cartão
```

---

Also in python directly:

```
logger.console(dict)

keys = dict.keys()
logger.console(keys[0])
```

Log shows:

```
{u'N\xba Cart\xe3o': u'123'}
Nº Cartão
```

How can I print it correctly? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must confirm that the file encoding is utf-8 (I did got errors when using WINDOWS-1252, or ISO-8859-15, first problematic char is name=Á.., and with Ẽ could not convert from utf-8).

The following test runs fine with RobotFramework 3.0.4 (in Python 2.7.15 and 3.6.6) in Linux.

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Collections

*** Variables ***
&{pc_dict}        one=1    2=2    ${3}=3    name=PC
&{ont_dict}       one=1    ${3}=3    name=ÁÇÕª    2=2

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    ${result}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    Dictionaries Should Be Equal    ${pc_dict}    ${ont_dict}

Key test
    &{dict}=    create dictionary    Nº Cartão=123
    Log Dictionary    ${dict}
    Collections.Dictionary Should Contain Key    ${dict}    Nº Cartão
```

Comment: Hello Helio, thanks for the answer but I have one more question:
Can I force the file encoding of a RF file like we do in python (# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-)?